# Inverse function theorem: Why is $\frac {\partial \phi }{\partial y} = \frac {-\partial F / \partial y} {\partial F / \partial z}$?

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus

Given $F(x,y,z) = 0$, $\partial F/\partial z \neq 0$ at $p_0$, by the implicit function theorem we can solve for $z=\phi(x,y)$ near $p_0$. I am told that

$$\frac {\partial \phi }{\partial y} = \frac {-\partial F / \partial y} {\partial F / \partial z}.$$

I am told that we can come to this conclusion by taking the total derivative

$$dF = \frac {\partial F} {\partial x}dx + \frac {\partial F} {\partial y}dy + \frac {\partial F} {\partial z}dz = 0,$$

setting $dx = 0$, and solving for $dz/dx$. I am aware that this has an interpretation in terms of differential forms, but for now it is just an algebraic manipulation to me.

Can someone point me to a proof that

$$\frac {\partial \phi }{\partial y} = \frac {-\partial F / \partial y} {\partial F / \partial z}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just differentiation and basic algebra manipulations.

Near $p_0$, you have
$$
F(x,y,\phi(x,y))=0.
$$
Now you want to differentiate with respect to $y$, and so you apply the chain rule:
$$
0=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\,\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}.
$$
And you just solve for $\partial \phi/\partial y$.

Comment: You are welcome :)